# How can add Bootstrap columns all the same height?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

here is my code
I'm using Bootstrap. How can I make three columns all the same height?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 panel" style="background-color: red">
        some content
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 panel" style="background-color: yellow">
        catz
        <img width="100" height="100" src="https://lorempixel.com/100/100/cats/">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 panel" style="background-color: blue">
        some more content
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution here using Bootstrap 4

[image]